# How PLINQ OrderBy works

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, linq, sorting

I want to implement my own multithreading sorting algorithm, but when I compare it with singlethread `Array.Sort` I get following results on 64MB random array: 16 seconds - PLINQ, 27 seconds - my realisation, 70 seconds - `Array.Sort`. It's clear that PLINQ is faster so I should enchance my realisation to overcome PLINQ's one. I am working with array and I know it, when PLINQ use `IEnumerable<T>` as source thus it cannot do any assumptions about collection size and so on while I can (and transform this knowledge into performance boost).

Now I found that PLINQ generate N partitions (N = Environment.ProcessorCount), then generate severals helpers and `Barrier`s (method `SortHelper<TInputOutput, TKey>.GenerateSortHelpers`, [see on referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/Utils/Sorting.cs,ccf571b94b50cf2a)), but I don't understand what is happening then. Why this barriers are required, how sort actually performs, why it uses partitions... Each partition could be sorted, but it doesn't guarantee that whole array will be in order. Maybe it merge them in some order, but how?.. I fell really deep in this rabbit hole but still confused what is going on.

The actual sorting is performed here:

```
internal override TInputOutput[] Sort()
{
    // Step 1.  Accumulate this partitions' worth of input.
    GrowingArray<TKey> sourceKeys = null;
    List<TInputOutput> sourceValues = null;

    BuildKeysFromSource(ref sourceKeys, ref sourceValues);

    Contract.Assert(sourceValues != null, "values weren't populated");
    Contract.Assert(sourceKeys != null, "keys weren't populated");

    // Step 2.  Locally sort this partition's key indices in-place.
    QuickSortIndicesInPlace(sourceKeys, sourceValues, m_indexState);

    // Step 3. Enter into the merging phases, each separated by several barriers.
    if (m_partitionCount > 1)
    {
        // We only need to merge if there is more than 1 partition.
        MergeSortCooperatively();
    }

    return m_sharedValues[m_partitionIndex];
}
```

It is called from all threads and finally we get sorted output.

Comment: PLINQ can easily find a collection size by using the `Count` extension method, which for most collections is O(1) so that's not a limitation on PLINQ.

Comment: Hmm, what? It's not about `How to calculate a size of a collection` which is pretty elementary, it's about how PLINQ works internally. I want to implement my own realisation which is using some priori information about collection, and use this information to boost the code and outperform PLINQ. It's not about `Count` method.

Comment: Are you asking for the actual implementation details or are you just trying to figure out why it's faster than your method?

Comment: I was refuting your claim that PLINQ "cannot do any assumptions about collection size"  It's pretty trivial for most collection types.

Comment: I think the former explains the latter. I know several things I can do to outperform PLINQ, but to implement them I need to know how it sorts. My single-core realisation outperform single-core `Enumerable.OrderBy`, but when parallelism appears, I just can't implement proper sorting algorithm. It's faster than single-core, I'm not a total dumb to reduce performance with multithreading, but it's obviosly not enough, because if there is faster algorithm than mine, the latter is not required and should be removed from mankind history. The only way to avoid it is enhancement of initial algorithm.

Comment: They are using an algorithm called [QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). The sorting in the sample you linked is happening in a routine named....QuickSort.

Comment: @Jeremy quicksort doesn't use any `Barrier`s and have no `Merge` step, hasn't any coop and so on. So it isn't. It may be used as one of steps, but it gives an intermediate result only.

Comment: after it performs quicksort, it calls MergeSortCooperatively, which uses said barriers to merge the results from each of the processes.

Comment: How? How these barriers are used, what logic is used here? There are severals multithreading sorting algorithms that uses *divide-and-conquer* way which are pretty simple, but I never saw an algorithm with barriers. You rewrite what I wrote above, but I don't understand how exactly these barriers are used and how merge is performed.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/06/07/10171827.aspx

Comment: Also I guess the partitioning was implemented in a way that avoids false sharing (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51553/Concurrency-Hazards-False-Sharing).

Comment: @tzachs it should be an answer. Finally, a good explanation what's going on in this evil method. And thank you a lot for second link. I never thought about array bounds check as cache invalidating instruction... It was something REALLY new I didn't know before. Pleasure to know it now.